# upgraded wamp before backing up mysql database

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I accidentally upgraded wamp before backing up the mysql database. i see the database files in data folder but nothing is loading. is there a way to get this up and running?

Comment: Do you now have 2 MYSQL folders i.e. `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql.old.version` and `\wamp\bin\mysql\new.version` ?

Comment: No and I do not have an old ibdata1 file

Comment: Then you are officially out of luck

Comment: What versions did you have originally? And what version did you upgrade to?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me when I used to use WampServer. In the end I used Windows' `Restore previous versions` feature on the whole `C:\wamp` folder.